# Keras model cannot fit with given data

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'm trying to predict next number in sequence.

You can see the data sample in google colab here:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QnkNtIo56V9wdQ4CMTm3LRSQaa6A9VmP?usp=sharing

(51 columns c0-c49 and the last 'y' is the first value from the next row)

data is scaled with StandardScaler:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaled_features = df.copy()
features = scaled_features[columns_a]

scaler = StandardScaler().fit(features.values)
features = scaler.transform(features.values)
scaled_features[columns] = features
```

after that is splitting in train and test data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(scaled_features, test_size=0.2, shuffle=False)
```

and reshaped for  LSTM input

```
Y_train=train["y"]
X_train=train.drop("y", axis=1)
Y_test=test["y"]
X_test=test.drop("y", axis=1)

X_train = X_train.to_numpy()
X_test = X_test.to_numpy()

X_train = X_train.reshape(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], 1)
X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], X_test.shape[1], 1)

X_train.shape
```

creating the model

```
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, GRU, Dense, Dropout
from matplotlib import pyplot

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2]), activation='relu', return_sequences=True)) 
model.add(LSTM(32, activation='relu' )) 
model.add(Dense(1))
#model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse',  metrics=['accuracy']) 
#print(model.summary())

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32, verbose=2)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test, batch_size=32, verbose=0)
print("Model Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

the output

```
Epoch 1/5
749/749 - 34s - loss: 1.2380 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 2/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2382 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 3/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2381 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 4/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2385 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Epoch 5/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2384 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
Model Accuracy: 0.00%
```

I'm pretty new at machine learning/AI and i don't know what's wrong in code

Any idea? Thank you

Comment: metrics=['accuracy'], accuracy is for classification, try changing it to metrics=['mse']. Let us know how that goes

Comment: Epoch 1/5
749/749 - 32s - loss: 1.2380 - mse: 1.2380
Epoch 2/5
749/749 - 32s - loss: 1.2381 - mse: 1.2381
Epoch 3/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2379 - mse: 1.2379
Epoch 4/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2380 - mse: 1.2380
Epoch 5/5
749/749 - 31s - loss: 1.2383 - mse: 1.2383
Model Accuracy: 4.90%

Comment: What's the problem? you now know that what's model accuracy is. Try with smaller model (something like 5 units in first layer, 2 units in second layer). Try different permutation of model for getting better accuracy. What's training data size?

Comment: The result is the same. Maybe this data set is not suitable for LSTM model. Anyway thank you for your time

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see your question. Training size is ~ 25000

Comment: Can you try batch size like 1000? Even though, you can't just reshape data into (batch_size, timesteps, no_features). You've to prepare it. Check out [this site](https://machinelearningmastery.com/reshape-input-data-long-short-term-memory-networks-keras/)